# How to define a pull request template in Gogs Server

Tags: git, gogs

Basically I want to define templates for issues and pull request in [Gogs](https://gogs.io/) repositories as [Github](https://github.com/) does ([see here](https://help.github.com/articles/about-issue-and-pull-request-templates/)) but I have failed with total success.

**I tried in the following ways:**

1. Create an ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md and PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md files at root level of my project.
2. Create a .gogs folder at root level of my project with ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md and PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md files
3. Create a .github folder at root level of my project with ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md and PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md files

None of these configurations worked for pull request templates. On the other hand both 1 and 2 worked for issues templates.

**What am I missing? I am doing something wrong? Maybe GOGs does not support templates for pull requests? I checked the official documentation without success.**

Any help will be well appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong filename for the pull request template.

The [expected file name for the pull request is `PULL_REQUEST.md`](https://github.com/gogs/gogs/blob/5a47301dbd85e8d3c240cdf2eb248974b7fe5f06/routes/repo/pull.go#L35) (i.e. the name does not include `_TEMPLATE`).

For comparison, the [expected filename for the issue template is `ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md`](https://github.com/gogs/gogs/blob/5a47301dbd85e8d3c240cdf2eb248974b7fe5f06/routes/repo/issue.go#L48).

Comment: Thanks! Now it is working!
I took the name of [github repository of gogs](https://github.com/gogs/gogs/tree/master/.github), but I suppose that it is there for Github only.